# How to find the most common character in a String

Tags: java, string

I have a quick question. How would I find the most common character in a string in Java. I know logically how to do it, but I am not sure if my syntax in correct:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args){


    String votes = "ABBAB";

    char[] StoringArray = votes.toCharArray();

    int numOFB = 0;
    int numOFA = 0;

    if (StoringArray.contains("A")) {
      numOFA++;
    } else if (StoringArray.contains("B")) {
              numOFAB++;
              }

    if (numOFA = numOFB) {
    System.out.println("Tie");
    } else if (numOFA > B) {
    System.out.println("A");
    } else {
    System.out.println("B");
    }

  }
}
```

Could anyone help me with how to correctly do this in Java?

Comment: Looks like your testing the frequency of specific chars rather than substrings

Comment: What do you mean with substring? Do you mean character? Syntax can be easily verified with any proper IDE.

Comment: Use == operator to check for equality, numOFA = numOFB is assigning numOFB to numOFA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was working with it, and I found this is the nicest way to do it:

```
String votes = "ABBAB";

char[] StoringArray = votes.toCharArray();

int B = 0;
int A = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < StoringArray.length; i ++) {
if (StoringArray[i] == 'A') {
  A++;
} else if (StoringArray[i] == 'B') {
          B++;
          }

}

if (A == B) {
System.out.println("Tie");
} else if (A > B) {
System.out.println("A");
} else {
System.out.println("B");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what you want is only to know the most common char, knowing the domain? because if you don't know it. It is more complicated.

Comment: take a look to my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not compare char Array with string, below logic should work and give you what you need:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

        String votes = "ABBAB";

        char[] storingArray = votes.toCharArray();

        int numOFB = 0;
        int numOFA = 0;
        for(char c : storingArray) {
            if(c == 'A') {
                numOFA++;
            }
            if(c == 'B') {
                numOFB++;
            }
        }
        if (numOFA == numOFB) {
            System.out.println("Tie");
        } else if (numOFA > numOFB) {
            System.out.println("A");
        } else {
            System.out.println("B");
        }

    }
```

There are couple of mistakes in your code:

1. You can not use `if (numOFA = numOFB)` it is not valid expression. You should use `==` to compare
2. You can not compare char Array with `contains` method. It should be used on `String` object

Comment: is it OK to just give code to what is clearly a homework problem?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak he seems novice so corrected the code and provided explanation of what he has done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said; it looks like you're counting the number of A's or B's, not the longest substring. Are you only analyzing a String composed of A's and B's?

Also, you're using = to check for equality when you should be using ==. I would recommend using an IDE like Eclipse which would show you when you're doing this.

Edit: also, you're not looping through the array. You're just checking if the String contains an A or a B and adding 1 if it does. You need to loop through the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a more abstract solution:

```
public class Counter{
        private char c;
        private int count;

        Counter(char c, int count){
            this.c=c;
            this.count=count;
        }

        public char getC() {
            return c;
        }
        public void setC(char c) {
            this.c = c;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
        public void addOcurrence() {
            this.count++;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {

            if(obj!=null)
                if(((Counter)obj).getC()== this.c)
                    return true;            

            return false;
        }
}



public static void main(String[] args){

        String votes = "whateveryouwanttoputhereorcanbefromaparameter";

            char[] storingArray = votes.toCharArray();

            List<Counter> listCounter = new ArrayList<Counter>();

            for(char aChar : storingArray){
                Counter compareCounter = new Counter(aChar,1);
                if(listCounter.contains(compareCounter)){
                    listCounter.get(listCounter.indexOf(compareCounter)).addOcurrence();
                }else{
                    listCounter.add(compareCounter);
                }
            }

            Counter max = listCounter.get(0);
            for( Counter c : listCounter){
                if(c.getCount() > max.getCount()){
                    max = c;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("the character with more ocurrence is: "+max.getC());
        }
```